# Return a case class that extends a trait

Tags: scala, traits, case-class

I need to define to return a case class that extends a trait:

```
trait Id {
  def id: Long
}

case class Person(name: String)

val john = Person("John") 
val johnWithId: Person with Id = /*person -> 123L*/ ???
```

Any idea how can I achieve that?

I'm trying to reduce the duplication of code, that's why I didn't declare a trait Person like this:

```
trait Id {
  def id: Long
}

trait Person {
  def name: String
}

case class PersonWithoutId(name: String) extends Person

case class PersonWithId(name: String, id: Long) extends Person with Id

val john = PersonWithoutId("John")
val johnWithId: Person with Id = PersonWithId(person.name, 123L)
```

Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit round-about way:

```
case class WithId[A](id: Long, value: A) extends Id
object WithId {
  implicit def getValue[A](x: WithId[A]): A = x.value
}

// elsewhere
val johnWithId = WithId(123, john)
```

`johnWithId` doesn't extend `Person` (so e.g. `johnWithId.isInstanceOf[Person]` is false), but can still be used where a `Person` is expected and `getValue`.

Comment: I was already using something like that and was just missing the implicit def that avoid to use `.value` each time. As I used many classes `WithXXX` it will just work at the first `sublevel` but at least it will reduce the verbosity a little.

Answer (score 3):

Once `Person` is already instantiated, it's too late - you can't change the instance `john` after it has already been instantiated. You can, however, instantiate a `Person with Id`:

```
val johnWithId: Person with Id = new Person("John") with Id {
  override def id: Long = 123L
}
```

Do note that this isn't really *equivalent* to using a `PersonWithId(name: String, id: Long)` case class, for example - `equals` and `hashcode` would *ignore* the ID in this implementation.

Answer (score 2):

```
val johnWithId: Person with Id = new Person("John") with Id { def id = 123L }
```

Comment: Do note that this isn't really equivalent to using a `PersonWithId(name: String, id: Long)` case class, for example - `equals` and `hashCode` would ignore the ID in this implementation (two instances with different IDs would be equal)

Comment: @TzachZohar Could you then maybe just undelete your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The most correct solution would be

```
case class Person(name: String, id: Long) extends Id
```

while you could in theory do

```
val johnWithId: Person with Id = new Person("John") with Id { def id = 123L }
```

as stated by Andrey, it wouldn't respect the overall `case class` contract because people with different ids and same name would be equal, since `id` wouldn't be used on the `equals` method

Comment: The object instantiated in the second line does respect the same `case class` contract as before: there are no new `case class` definitions, and neither of `equals`/`hashCode`/`toString` are overridden, therefore only the arguments to the constructor will be considered during the `hashCode` computation etc. I didn't expect any miracles from this code, so I wasn't surprised when the miracle didn't occur...